# Size of boot image is 48 sectors -> No emulation

Tags: boot, centos, iso-image

I am  trying create iso (supporting uefi) as follows,

```
genisoimage \
    -follow-links \
    -o $dir/$iso_name \
    -b isolinux.bin \
    -c boot.cat \
    -no-emul-boot \
    -eltorito-alt-boot \
    -eltorito-boot images/efiboot.img \
    -V 'CENTOS 7' \
    -boot-load-size 4 \
    -boot-info-table\
     -R -J -v -T \
    $ISOLINUX_DIR/
```

But am facing the error as below,

> Size of boot image is 48 sectors -> No emulation
>   Size of boot image is 4 sectors -> mkisofs: Error - boot image '/net/*.*.*.*/CentOS/isolinux/images/efiboot.img' has not an allowable size.

Answer (score 2):

You did not mark the second boot image as being for EFI rather than x86 BIOS.
Depending on the variant of genisoimage, this may be done by option "-e"
instead of "-eltorito-boot". It should be accompanied by an own occurence
of option "-no-emul-boot".

Options "-boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table" apply to the BIOS
image "isolinux.bin" and need to be moved before the separator
"-eltorito-alt-boot".

Try

```
genisoimage \
    -follow-links \
    -o $dir/$iso_name \
    -b isolinux.bin \
    -c boot.cat \
    -no-emul-boot \
    -boot-load-size 4 \
    -boot-info-table \
    -eltorito-alt-boot \
    -e images/efiboot.img \
    -no-emul-boot \
    -V 'CENTOS 7' \
    -R -J -v -T \
    $ISOLINUX_DIR/
```

If your genisoimage does not offer option -e, try instead:

```
xorriso -as mkisofs \
    ...above.options...
```

(Option -T will be ignored.)

Have a nice day :)

Thomas